# Trigger bootstrap js collpase() function in angular/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 with Angular 2 for collapsing/hiding content. I need to be able to collapse when double clicking on the button. I created a function for this, but can't seem to access the .collapse() function in my typescript

[docs for bootstrap collapase](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp)

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <button (dblclick)="toggleMe($event)" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
toggleMe($event){
   event.target.collpase('toggle')    //is not a function
}
```

How can I access toggle function so I can use it in my double click function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was not able to find a perfect solution rather then using jquery, which I did not want to use in my application. I was able to achieve better functionality using Angular Animate instead of using Bootstrap Collpase, see some code below:

```
 <button (dblclick)="toggleMe()" type="button">Simple collapsible</button>

  <div [@visibilityChanged]="visiblityState" >
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

.ts

Add animations to a @Component, don't forget to import Angular Animations to you app.

```
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';


@Component({
   selector: 'my-component',
   templateUrl: './tree-search-node.component.html',
      animations: [
       trigger('visibilityChanged', [
       state('shown', style({
                      height: '0px',
                      opacity: '0',
                      overflow: 'hidden',
                     // display: 'none'
        })),
       state('hidden', style({
                       height: '*',
                       opacity: '1',
                      // display: 'block'
    })),
  transition('shown => hidden',animate('200ms ease-in')),
  transition('hidden => shown', animate('200ms ease-out')),
      ])
    ]
 })


 visiblityState = 'shown';

   toggleMe() {
      if (this.visiblityState === 'hidden')
           this.visiblityState = 'shown'
      else
            this.visiblityState = 'hidden'
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *toggleMe* function should look like this:

```
toggleMe($event){
   $($event.target).collpase('toggle');
}
```

That's because you need jQuery object to access *collapse* function, but in event.target you have pure DOM object.

Comment: any way to use it without jquery, purely angular/typescript

Comment: Probably no, but there is no reason for avoiding jQuery here. Bootstrap requires jQuery to work, so you probably have jQuery already on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Hey using $close has always worked with bootstrap modals using angular for me.

```
  <div class="modal-footer hidden-print">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.saveTeam($close())"> Save </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$close()">Cancel</button>

    </div>
</form>
```